# Shared Prefference is not saving the data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am storing the status of togglebutton using a sharedpreffrence.
I am putting "ON" if toggle button is checked and "OFF" if toggle button is unchecked.
But when I am retriveing the status , it always returns "ON"
Here is the code

```
SharedPreferences.Editor  shfEditMessageSMS;
SharedPreferences  shfResponderMessage;
shfResponderMessage=getSharedPreferences("MESSAGE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
shfEditMessageSMS=shfResponderMessage.edit();

toggleStatus=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonStatus);

toggleStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{           
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(((ToggleButton)v).isChecked())
        {
            shfEditMessageSMS.putString("SMSRESPONDERONOFF", "ON");
            shfEditMessageSMS.commit();

            showNotification("ON");                   
        }
        else
        {
            shfEditMessageSMS=shfResponderMessage.edit();
            shfEditMessageSMS.putString("SMSRESPONDERONOFF", "OFF");
            shfEditMessageSMS.commit();

            showNotification("OFF");
            String SMSResponderOnOrOff=shfResponderMessage.getString("SMSRESPONDERONOFF", "NONE");
            Log.i("SMS Responder on click "+SMSResponderOnOrOff," "); 
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see in the code that if toggle button in unchecked  i am doing

```
shfEditMessageSMS.putString("SMSRESPONDERONOFF", "OFF");
shfEditMessageSMS.commit();
```

but when I am retrieving and printing using log

```
String SMSResponderOnOrOff=shfResponderMessage.getString("SMSRESPONDERONOFF", "NONE");
Log.i("SMS Responder on click "+SMSResponderOnOrOff," ");
```

It always shows "ON" in the logs.

What could be the problem.
thanks.

Comment: Two things.  First, try checking the value returned by `commit()` to make sure that the value has actually been committed.  Second, why not use a `boolean` instead of the string values "ON" and "OFF"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have implement the Same thing in my application. Might Help you out to Solve your Problem.Though Could Not able to Find out the Mistake you have done in your Code. Refere below code below.

```
boolean on; 
 public SharedPreferences spref; 
  final String PREF_NAME="preferences"; 
 ToggleButton tb;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.fb_intermidiate);
    spref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    on = spref.getBoolean("On", true);  //default is true
    if (on = true) 
    {
      tb.setChecked(true);
    }       else
    {
      tb.setChecked(false);
    }
    back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_back); 
    //back.setText(R.string.back_button_in_settings);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });  } 

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {

    on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
    if (on) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "On : Notification will be Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("On", true); // value to store
        editor.commit();

    } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Off : Notification will be Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor =spref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("On", false); // value to store
        editor.commit();
    }   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with saving a String array. I "solved" the problem by incrementing a variable on each save.

```
    public void saveProfileList(Context context) {
            SharedPreferences sharedprefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = sharedprefs.edit();
            editor.putStringSet("vpnlist", profiles.keySet());

            // For reasing I do not understand at all 
            // Android saves my prefs file only one time 
            // if I remove the debug code below :(
            int counter = sharedprefs.getInt("counter", 0);
            editor.putInt("counter", counter+1);
            editor.apply();


    }
```

There seems to be a bug somewhere in the android code that does not always detect the sharedpreferences as changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a vague recollection that it can take a while for the value to be read back correctly. You can solve that by encapsulating the value and store it in a variable, from where you also retrieve it. You should also consider using `apply()` instead of `commit()` since it does not interrupt the UI thread. Thus, I propose something like:

```
public class Preferences {
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private static final String KEY = "SMSRESPONDERONOFF";
    private String mValue;

    public Preferences(SharedPreferences prefs) {
        mPrefs = prefs;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        if (mValue == null) {
            mValue = mPrefs.getString(KEY, "NONE");
        }

        return mValue;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        mValue = value;
        mPrefs.edit().putString(KEY, value).apply();
    }
}
```